# allow logging Traceback in file but do not display in console Python

Tags: python, logging

how can I set false exc_info for console but leave for writing to file?

config.conf

```
version: 1
formatters:
  simple:
    format: '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
filters:
  warnings_and_below:
    "()": log.filter_maker
    level: WARNING
    sense: below
  errors_and_above:
    "()": log.filter_maker
    level: ERROR
    sense: above
handlers:
  outconsole:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: INFO
    formatter: simple
    filters: [warnings_and_below] 
    stream: ext://sys.stdout
  errconsole:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: WARNING
    formatter: simple
    filters: [errors_and_above]
    stream: ext://sys.stderr
  file_handler:
    class: logging.FileHandler
    level: DEBUG
    formatter: simple
    filename: info.log
    encoding: utf8
    mode: w

root:
  level: DEBUG
  handlers: [file_handler, outconsole, errconsole]
  propagate: no
```

log.py

```
import logging.config
from functools import *
import logging
import yaml

def filter_maker(level, sense):
    level = getattr(logging, level) # get the actual numeric value from the string
    if sense == 'below':  # return a function which only passes if level is at or below threshold
        def filter(record):
            return record.levelno <= level
    else:  # return a function which only passes if level is at or above threshold
        def filter(record):
            return record.levelno >= level
    return filter

with open("logging.conf", "r") as f:
        config = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
        logging.config.dictConfig(config)



Logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

Logger.error("Some error")
Logger.error("Some error", exc_info=True)
```

what I need is for the last two lines to always send to the errconsole handler exc_info=False, and to the file_handler always exc_info=True. Is this possible on one logger or do I need to configure two ?

Answer (score 0):

Use formatters to have different formatting for different handlers. For example, define something like

```
class NoExceptionFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def formatException(self, exc_info):
        return ''
```

and attach an instance of it to the console handler(s).